# Search in text in link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
​<div id="main">
  <div>
     <div> 
         <a href="/test/number/1">1asd</a>
         <div>
             <div>
                 <a href="/test/number/1/phone/0">1fdf</a>
             </div>
         </div>
      </div>         
  </div>
  <div>
     <div> 
         <a href="/test/number/2">2a2d</a>
      </div>         
  </div>
  <div>
     <div> 
         <a href="/test/number/3">33</a>
         <div>
             <div>
                 <a href="/test/number/3/phone/0">33df</a>
             </div>
         </div>
      </div>         
  </div>
​</div>​

​function(num)​{
    $('#main a').each(function(){

    })    

    return false;
}​
```

I would like doing:

if num == 1 then this should return me TRUE, because:

isset **`<a href="/test/number/1/phone/0">1fdf</a>`**

this link have number and phone

if num == 2 then this should return me FALSE, because:

isset **`<a href="/test/number/2">2a2d</a>`**

this link have number and NOT HAVE phone

if num == 3 then this should return me TRUE, because:

isset **`<a href="/test/number/3/phone/0">1fdf</a>`**

this link have number and phone

if num > 3 then this should return me FALSE, because:

not isset link with number/4 etc

Thanks for help!

http://jsfiddle.net/h7Wda/

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about...!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fiddle with the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/h7Wda/7/

You basically check if `number/1/phone` is located in the href of the  element:

```
 $(this).attr('href').indexOf('number/1/phone')
```

Same for the `number/3/phone` case.

Any other value will return false.

Comment: cassi.lup: Upvote requires 15 rep: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up The OP lost 22 rep by asking this question.